# Addition of free space from Hard disk 2 to Hard disk 1

Tags: windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, disk-space

I have two hard disks of 20Gb and 10Gb. My 20Gb hard disk is my C drive which contains the OS and my 10Gb Hard disk is my D drive which is empty.

I want to add my free space of disk 2 to disk 1. I saw many articles on Google but they aren't clear.

Comment: Which OS (a tad more specific than just 'windows' please. E.g. win7 has storage spaces. Xp has not). Also 10GB and 20GB? Is one external or are both internal. And do you want to be able to boot when the external drive is disconnected for a reason (e.g. is the cable falls out).

Comment: If these are really 10 GB and 20 GB drives, I would be worried about their age, and them approaching the end of their service lives. You could "stripe" them (depending on OS support) but that has serious data assurance considerations (see [What happens to a RAID 0 array if some of the constituent drives are unavailable?](https://superuser.com/q/692415/53590) for further discussion; while that question is about OS X, the general considerations are the same). It's probably easier, and far less risky, to purchase a new terabyte-class (assuming desktop form factor) drive and use that.

Comment: They are not of 10Gb and 20Gb. For simplicity purpose i mentioned. And the OS is actually windows 2012r2 which is a server OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar situation once, and solved it by moving user profiles from C to D. Those directories contained *a lot* of files so this made sense.

Say your user account is called U, and another (admin) account is called A.

- Log in as A
- Move U's profile (`C:\Users\U`) to your D: drive, let's say `D:\Users\U`
- Create a symbolic link from `C:\Users\U` to `D:\Users\U`
- Repeat for other users, if necessary
- Log in as U.

**Note:** Both drives need to be formatted as NTFS for this to work. If one is FAT32, you can convert it to NTFS using the *[convert.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb456984.aspx)* tool.

Comment: I don't think that is what the OP is asking. With how poorly the question is written, I don't know how anyone can answer without simply guessing.

Comment: @CharlieRB you're right, we can only assume that (s)he is looking for a way to utilize the free space on drive D in some way.

Comment: Thanks Berend. I tried the solution but i don't have any other user account. With same account i tried creating symbolic link but there is an error message "Cannot create a file when that file already exists".

Comment: This won't work with only one account because certain files in the user profile will be locked as long as that user is logged on. If you have only one user, add a new one (with admin privileges), and delete it afterwards if you want.